# Linux Mint on laptop fails, gives grub error

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install the latest Linux Mint onto my laptop via a USB stick. The laptop previously had Ubuntu, and it had a separate `/home` partition. I'm overriding and reformatting the `/` partition, and leaving the `/home` partition in place. I'm replacing Ubuntu with Mint, but trying to keep my personal data.

The install process seems to go just fine, right up until I reboot. Then I get this error:

```
error: file `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

I thought maybe I hadn't specified which partition to boot from when installing, so I went back twice and re-installed to make sure, but I can't determine anything about the install process that I am not setting correctly. Not that I can tell, anyway.

How do I resolve this error so that I can get my Mint up and running?

Comment: Maybe the install script just can't identify your setup correctly and you'll need to install grub manually. Are you using grub or grub-2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall grub. Plug in you USB dongle with Mint on it and run a Live Session. Open the console and type

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

Then reboot and look if it works.